# Can't Logout in Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with Nvidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 64-bit, logout

I know more people with this issue: After we upgraded to 12.04, we can't log out with Nvidia drivers enabled, I got a blank screen, sometimes with fuzzy words (like X server crash), and after some seconds the PC reboots. If I uninstall Nvidia drivers, I can log out without problems. I can't find any fix, I have tried with current and current-updates. Anyone have solved this? It's a bug?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Nvidia drivers seem to have problems reloading during X server restart.

I faced this very same issue myself, using a GT520 card. The answer to me at least was posted [on this forum](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?70619-Logout-freeze-using-Nvidia-Proprietary-driver-%28latest-and-even-older-versions%29/page2&s=4591cc6f611a2fa1613c3388e5decfb5):

For now, you can go around the issue by setting the Nvidia driver to persistent mode:

```
nvidia-smi -pm 1
```

Fixed it for me.